# Display a list with hyperlink in Python template

Tags: python, markup, jinja2

I have a list of users. And i want to display it in template:

```
{%- for user in listed_of_users -%}
        <P>{{ user.name  }}</P>
        {%- endfor -%}
```

i want to create hyperlink link to user's profile for each user using predefined function "create_link". This function will return the hyper link for each object. So i write a function like below:

```
def users_list(users):
    return jinja2.Markup('# '.join(map(create_link, users)) )
```

It will return a list like:

```
User1# User2# User3# User4#...
```

And i have hyperlink under each username.

I display it in template as a string using this syntax:

```
{{ users_list(listed_of_users)}}
```

But, I want to display each user like the format above. I tried:

```
{%- for user in users_list(listed_of_users) -%}
        <P>{{ user  }}</P>
        {%- endfor -%}
```

However, it does not work. Can someone help me correct it?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: With <P>{{ user  }}</P>. It return a string of HTML text. With <P>{{ user.name  }}</P>, it return nothing. So it mean that the users_list function have changed the original list, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one thing, in your example, `'# '.join(map(create_link, users))` creates a long string, so you can't iterate over it the way you are trying to do. You could write a lambda expression and do a double map or something, but why not save yourself the trouble and use the `create_link` function in your template, so if `create_link` returns valid HTML for a hyperlink, you could shorten what you write to:

```
{%- for user in listed_of_users -%}
   <p> {{ user | create_link | safe }} </p>
{%- endfor -%}
```

To set this up, you need to register create_link as a filter called `create_link`. Since the `create_link` function only takes in one value, you really only need to add one line of code:

```
environment.filters["create_link"] = create_link
```

(where `environment` is whatever `jinja2` environment you are using to render your templates). As a bonus, this means you can also use the filter anywhere. You can find out more on the [jinja2 docs on writing custom filters](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#writing-filters).

Comment: Thank you very much jeff. I finally make it using another build-in function i haven't found out at that time. But this filter way is really promising. I will find out more about it.